# bitcoind not booting, tons of output in debug.log file

Tags: bitcoind

running `$ bitcoind -server` just hangs, when I look at my debug.log file it's going really crazy:

```
2016-03-19 01:26:51 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000005f9ff6fe1e9e19f6f64dd9c1167077b7de4b93146df2e6f1004  height=192099  log2_work=68.48247  tx=5576861  date=2012-08-03 09:07:41 progress=0.022371  cache=46.6MiB(128445tx)
```

The docs show me that running bitcoind should have asked me to set a password, but I never got that. Is something going wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation on [bitcoin.org](https://bitcoin.org/en/full-node) is currently out of date.

As of Bitcoin Core 0.12, there is no need for the `rpcuser` and `rpcpassword` in `bitcoin.conf` anymore, as [cookie authentication](https://bitcoin.org/en/release/v0.12.0#rpc-random-cookie-rpc-authentication) is now used when they are not present.

Comment: Thanks, I'm out of upvotes but will upvote you when I get the chance again in 6h. Where can I find the most up to date docs for Bitcoin?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that `$ bitcoind` is just downloading the blockchain, the docs here: https://bitcoin.org/en/full-node seem to be incorrect. :\